# How to verify modem is a fax modem?

Tags: ubuntu, modem

An HP 8440p laptop is outfitted with Ubuntu 16.04. It has a RJ11 telephone port, which may be a fax modem.  This [quick-spec](https://dustinimages.azureedge.net/media/d200001001277336/elitebook-8440p.pdf) document, provided by usr K-att, indicate it is a fax modem.

[image]

Goals include:

- Verifying from the command line that the said hardware is a fax modem
- Verifying that the drivers and other necessary conditions are satisfied for a faxing software.

What are the terminal commands to achieve said goals?

lsusb returns:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b15e Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 03f0:231d Hewlett-Packard Broadcom 2070 Bluetooth Combo
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

lspci returns:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DMI (rev 11)
00:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 11)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor System Management Registers (rev 11)
00:08.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor Semaphore and Scratchpad Registers (rev 11)
00:08.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor System Control and Status Registers (rev 11)
00:08.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor Miscellaneous Registers (rev 11)
00:10.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link (rev 11)
00:10.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Routing and Protocol Registers (rev 11)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset KT Controller (rev 06)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 06)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM57 Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218M [NVS 3100M] (rev a2)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
44:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 (rev 35)
45:06.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller (rev 06)
45:06.1 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter (rev 25)
45:06.2 CardBus bridge: Ricoh Co Ltd RL5c476 II (rev bb)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-Core Registers (rev 04)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 04)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 04)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 04)
ff:03.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller (rev 04)
ff:03.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Target Address Decoder (rev 04)
ff:03.4 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Test Registers (rev 04)
ff:04.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Control Registers (rev 04)
ff:04.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Address Registers (rev 04)
ff:04.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Rank Registers (rev 04)
ff:04.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Thermal Control Registers (rev 04)
ff:05.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Control Registers (rev 04)
ff:05.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Address Registers (rev 04)
ff:05.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Rank Registers (rev 04)
ff:05.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Thermal Control Registers (rev 04)
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not an ethernet port?

Comment: @fuzzydrawings  Yes, the RJ45 ethernet port is next to the RJ11 modem port.

Comment: An actual modem port. How quaint. I would run `lspci` to see if its recognized by the kernel.

Comment: @fuzzydrawings Maybe I missed it, so I posted `lspci` output in the OP

Comment: From the documentation :)? https://dustinimages.azureedge.net/media/d200001001277336/elitebook-8440p.pdf Quickspecs: WiFi Adapter

Comment: Omg. Hylafax alive :)? I used it twenty years ago.... And mgetty-fax also....

Comment: Maybe it is connected to the usb bus. Could you add output of `lsusb`

Comment: If you still have the original OS for the laptop (Windows?), that might help to figure out where the hardware actually sits. There is no "standard" way how modems appear. Start with anything that looks like a serial port. In particular, there won't be a "just type the following commands, and there you have it" answer.

Comment: @fuzzydrawings    `lsusb` output is posted in OP

Comment: See http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01609465.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer:

Googling for modem drivers for this laptop finds [this](https://driverpack.io/en/laptops/hp/elitebook-8440p/modem), which offers an "LSI HDA" driver. Googling for "LSI HDA" indicates that it really seems to be a "High-Definition Audio" modem, which means it's probably connected to your internal sound card (and your `lspci` shows that it's indeed Intel HDA).

So the next step would be to look at the codecs:

```
cat /proc/asound/card*/codec\#*
```

and see if you can find anything there that looks like it could be the modem. Maybe they just connected one suitable pin of the generic codec to the RJ11...

It also probably means that it's a "Softmodem", I'd assume you'd just get an audio stream to and from the phone line (and I can't even imagine how they'd do dialing... generating the two-tone dial codes in software?).

That in particular means all FAX functionality is also in software.

There is some software-only modem Linux stuff out there, but last time I looked, it was not really mature. If you find something that's working for you, be sure to leave an answer here as well.

---

Looking at the codec dump, the following seems to be your modem:

```
Codec: LSI Generic HDMI
Address: 1
MFG Function Id: 0x2 (unsol 1)
Vendor Id: 0x11c11040
Subsystem Id: 0x103c3066
Revision Id: 0x100200
Modem Function Group: 0x1
```

(You could have found that yourself, all I did was read through the dump, and the words "LSI" and "Modem" stand out, though "HDMI" is a bit confusing here)

Googling for the vendor ID finds that apparently the company that made this is called **Agere** before it merged into LSI, and it also finds [this driver](https://github.com/george-hopkins/agrsm), together with various reports that this is difficult to get working (e.g. [here](https://oldforum.puppylinux.com/viewtopic.php?t=44376)).

The driver code has been last changed 7 years ago, so it may or may not work with current kernels. Also, the peer Nvidia HDMI HDA codec is not on the [supported list](https://github.com/george-hopkins/agrsm/blob/master/Supported.txt).

So in principle you have everything to make this work, but you'll very likely need some C and kernel skills to actually do that through small modifications. You'll also probably want to do some more googling.

And I didn't look at the driver in detail, so I don't know if it supports the FAX modes.

Also possibly relevant, from [1st_README](https://github.com/george-hopkins/agrsm/blob/master/1st_Readme.txt):

> The agrmodemlib.o_shipped was precompiled at LSI Inc., with a 32 bit compiler.
> Hence the current release is not compatible with x86_64 (64 bit) operating systems,
> though x86_64 motherboards general support 32 bit emualtions under which the modems should function.
>
> The 11c11040 support was originally for a Red Star Linux release with 2.6.20 kernel.
> Updates to maintain compatibility with emerging kernels have been done by several volunteers.
> The most recent patches are from Nikolay Zhuravlev xxor@mail.ru supporting
> compiling into 2.6.32 kernels..
>
> There is included Proprietary USB modem code. This blocks legal compiling
> under Linux, since 2.6.25 kernels.  A USB code free variant has been
> requested from LSI maintainer Soumyendu Sarkar.  But pending its arrival [...]

That explains why it never made the mainline kernel. It also may not work if you are using 64bit kernel.

Comment: @drikt  Thank you for the insights.  The prescribed `cat` command output is posted at:  [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/raw/1zqkEdTB).  I look forward to any insights gleaned from the pastebin file